# How to order boxes in boxplots by the medians of a numerical variable in a dataframe in base R

Tags: r, boxplot

I have a dataframe with three variables; one ("group") is a factor with two levels, one ("word") is a character vector, and one ("duration") is numeric. For example:

```
DATA <- data.frame(
  group = c(rep("prefinal",10), rep("final", 10)),
  word  = c(sample(LETTERS[1:5], 10, replace = T), sample(LETTERS[1:5], 10, replace = T)),
  duration   = rnorm(20)
)
DATA
      group word    duration
1  prefinal    C  0.16378771
2  prefinal    E  0.13370196
3  prefinal    A  0.69112398
4  prefinal    B  0.21499187
5  prefinal    D -0.28998279
6  prefinal    D -2.00353522
7  prefinal    A  0.37842555
8  prefinal    E  1.62326170
9  prefinal    A -0.26294929
10 prefinal    B -0.54276322
11    final    D  1.32772171
12    final    E -1.84902285
13    final    C  0.01058158
14    final    E  1.49529743
15    final    B  0.55291290
16    final    A -0.35484820
17    final    D -0.16822110
18    final    A  0.88667458
19    final    E  0.70889916
20    final    B  1.12217332
```

I'd like to depict the durations of the words by group in boxplots:

```
boxplot(DATA$duration ~ DATA$group + DATA$word, 
        xaxt="n",
        col = rep(c("blue", "red"), 5))
axis(1, at = seq(from=1.5, to= 10.5, by=2), labels = sort(unique(DATA$word)), cex.axis = 0.9)
```

R seems to order the boxes in alphabetical order (of the "word" variable) by default.

**EDIT:**

However I'd prefer that the boxes be sorted by the median durations (in descending order) the items in the "word" variable have in the "prefinal" group. How can that be achieved? 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reorder the levels of `DATA$word`according to their median. The `-` before `DATA$duration` is to sort it in descending order.

```
DATA$word <-  reorder(DATA$word, -DATA$duration, FUN = median)

boxplot(DATA$duration ~ DATA$group + DATA$word, 
        xaxt="n",
        col = rep(c("blue", "red"), 5))
axis(1, at = seq(from=1.5, to= 10.5, by=2), labels = levels(DATA$word), cex.axis = 0.9)
```

[image]

You can do the same for the subgroup of `prefinal`. But it requires an additional step:

```
ordered_levels <- levels(with(DATA[DATA$group == "prefinal",], reorder(word, -duration, FUN = median)))

DATA$word <- factor(DATA$word, levels = ordered_levels)
```

[image]

Comment: But isn't the median in the red box for "C" higher than the respective median for "D"? So the order of the boxes should be "E", "C", "B", "D", "A", right? Also, the boxes do not seem in effect to be reordered by median when I run  your code on my data.

Comment: Well, each box is the result of grouping by `word` and `group`. However the sorting is done by the median of just `word`, as was asked.

Comment: Please see my EDIT to the original post

Comment: Yeah, that's it! Thanks a lot. I'm not familiar with the levels() function. Can you explain it a little?

Comment: `levels()` just returns the unique levels of a factor-variable as a character vector. Decisive in this case is their order. We then overwrite the old levels order with our new levels order.